# Exception handling while running threads

Tags: java, elasticsearch, threadpool, completable-future

I have a an application which has a kafka consumer and updates Elastic search according to the data it receives.

My issue is that when ever ES goes down, the kafka consumer stops completely and doesn't restart.

I believe its due to how my ES code is running:

```
public CompletionStage<SearchResponse> executeSearch(SearchRequest searchRequest) {
        CompletableFuture<SearchResponse> f = new CompletableFuture<>();

        client.searchAsync(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT, new ActionListener<SearchResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(SearchResponse searchResponse) {
                f.complete(searchResponse);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {

                throw new Exception();  // I am guessing because of this
            }
        });
        return f;
}
```

If I change my `onFailure` method to:

```
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {

                f.complete(null);
            }
```

It works perfectly but I dont understand why throwing an exception leads to this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This requires more information on how your consumer is structured. However, it is possible that your exception is breaking out of your polling loop. When you do not propagate the exception, your polling loop is intact and continues to handle future events.

Comment: @mohro What information would you need about the consumer? Its a kafka streams consumer with a processor which is internally calling this.

Comment: Code snippet of your Kafka Consumer implementation. Without looking at how it is written, it would be difficult to determine how it handles exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that need a solution, I changed my code to below for it to work with exception:

```
public void onFailure(Exception e) {
    f.completeExceptionally(new Exception());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also potentially relevant are the `exceptionally` method and the `handle` method from `CompletableFuture`

`CompletableFuture.exceptionally((ex)-> )` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-